# Parameters passed by value displayed incorrectly in the visual studio 2015 x64 debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, 64-bit

x86 works fine.
[x86 debug values screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBgAU.png)

But x64 display incorrectly.
[x64 debug values screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MJuS.png)

Here is the code.

```
struct vector3 { float x, y, z; };

vector3 mul(vector3 v1, vector3 v2)
{
    vector3 v3 = { v1.x * v2.x, v1.y * v2.y, v1.z * v2.z };
    return v3;
}

int main()
{
    vector3 a = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    vector3 b = { 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f };
    vector3 c = mul(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I first noticed this in one of my personal projects and was able to replicate it in a new project (images above are from new project).

I'm wonder what is causing it.
Maybe a bad install, or a VS bug?
Is it able to be replicated on other machines?

This is as simple as I can make the code.

Note this code works fine on x64:

```
struct vector2 { float x, y; };

vector2 mul(vector2 v1, vector2 v2)
{
    vector2 v3 = { v1.x * v2.x, v1.y * v2.y };
    return v3;
}

int main()
{
    vector2 a = { 1.0f, 1.0f };
    vector2 b = { 2.0f, 2.0f };
    vector2 c = mul(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jonas, those are pictures of the debugger window, not code

Comment: Are you sure it is the same code? Honestly it simply looks like in the first example the vectors passed to the function were properly initialized, and in the second example they were not.

Comment: Also you should add a [Minimum Compilable Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially since you are saying you could reproduce it in a new project.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yes it is exactly the same. I only changed from x84 to x64 in the top toolbar.

Comment: Just tested in VS pro 2015 (version 14.0.25431.03 update 3), can not reproduce.

Comment: Did you rebuild the project after switching the build configuration? Try to clean the project up, then rebuild

Comment: You should be aware that the values of variables might not be availebl any longer after they were used for the last time in a function. Normally the debugger should know when a variable is valid or not. But depending on optimization this is not always easy. You could try to show the values one line earlier before the values are used.

Comment: Did you change any options in the X64 Debug? like turn the optimizations on or prevent generating debug informations ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Completely stock settings.

Comment: @user3451711 If I were you, I would try the dumbest solutions like create new project and copy my code into it. Try it on another machine. Delete VS and re install it.. and those things.. your code seems valid and your problem is not reproducible (until you did something bad but you can not remember)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Visual studio fixed the problem.